# JPA stackoverflow error when fetching data

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities namely Teacher and Club, I need to retrieve the teacher data along with its related club and/or sports.
I a bit new to `JPA` so am having trouble debugging the stack overflow error I get when I use the `findAll` method on the Teacher repository.
I had tried adding `@JsonIgnore` annotation to my one-to-many annotation to deal with the recursion problem as suggested in some similar questions but was still getting problems and am not sure how exactly it's supposed to solve the problem.

TEACHER ENTITY:

```java
  @Entity
@Table(name = "TEACHER")
public class Teacher {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Collection<ClubTeacher> clubTeachersById;
  

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = true, length = 25)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Teacher teacher = (Teacher) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(teacher.id) : teacher.id != null) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(teacher.name) : teacher.name != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "TICClub" ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Collection<ClubTeacher> getClubTeachersById() {
        return clubTeachersById;
    }

    public void setClubTeachersById(Collection<ClubTeacher> clubTeachersById) {
        this.clubTeachersById = clubTeachersById;
    }

}
```

CLUB ENTITY:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLUB_TEACHER", schema = "abbc", catalog = "")
@IdClass(ClubTeacherPK.class)
public class ClubTeacher implements Serializable {
    private String tic;
    private String clubkey;
    private Teacher teacherByTic;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TIC", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getTic() {
        return tic;
    }

    public void setTic(String tic) {
        this.tic = tic;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLUBKEY", nullable = false, length = 25)
    public String getClubkey() {
        return clubkey;
    }

    public void setClubkey(String clubkey) {
        this.clubkey = clubkey;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ClubTeacher that = (ClubTeacher) o;

        if (tic != null ? !tic.equals(that.tic) : that.tic != null) return false;
        if (clubkey != null ? !clubkey.equals(that.clubkey) : that.clubkey != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = tic != null ? tic.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (clubkey != null ? clubkey.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TIC", referencedColumnName = "Id", nullable = false,insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Teacher getTeacherByTic() {
        return teacherByTic;
    }
    public void setTeacherByTic(Teacher teacherByTic) {
        this.teacherByTic = teacherByTic;
    }
}
```

STACK TRACE:

```
2021-02-17 21:42:56.516 ERROR 20546 --- [nio-3005-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1027) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
....
```

Comment: Did you override equals/hashCode?

Comment: yes i used intellij to generate my entities, they are overriden automatically just did not include them on the question.

Comment: The one from Teacher calls the one from club that calls the one from teacher etc. In order to fix this, you can just exclude e.g. the collections of `ClubTeacher` from the equals/hashCode.

Comment: Sounds good let, me try that thanks

Comment: Excluded the hash/equals code to no avail , i guess that is not the problem

Comment: Can you share the stack trace and the new equals/hashCode?

Comment: Edited the question with the original hash/Equals code as well as part of the stack trace

Comment: What about adding `transient` to the `Collection`?

Comment: Worked! thanks a bunch but why did it work?

Comment: Gson tried to serialize that teacher what required the club what required the teacher etc. `transient` means that variable should be ignored for serialization.

Comment: Alright got it will look more into it thanks again